# Applying Tchebychev's Inequality

Tags: variance, random-variable

Let $f$ be a function defined by :

$f(x) = 0$ if $x<1$

$f(x) = (\alpha-1)x^{-\lambda}$ if $x\ge1$

1)Determine $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ such that $f(x)$ is a probability density function of a random variable with expected value equal to 2.

2)Determine the variance of $X$

3)Based on Tchebyshev's inequality find a real $a$ such that $P(|X-2|>a)<0.01$.

I've solved the first 2 question and got :

$\alpha =  \lambda = 3 $ (Correct me if I'm wrong)

$Var(x) = \infty$ (Not so sure about this)

For the third question :

Tchebyshev's inequality : $P((X-E[X])>kσ)<\frac{1}{k^2}$

Comparing this with the equation given in the 3rd question , wouldn't this imply that $a = kσ$ with $\frac{1}{k^2}=0.01$?

However due to the fact that the i got $\infty$ as the variance , the standard deviation $σ$ would also be infinity and hence a would be $\infty$.

I'm confused about this and i have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I'd be glad if anyone can help me.(Let me know if you need me to post the calculations for 1) and 2))

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this an exercise from a textbook? If yes, you should add a 'self-study' tag. You also need to modify the expression of the probability density function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out , and I'm not sure if this exercise is taken from a textbook or not , I was just handed out some practice problems to get ready for my exams.

Comment: What values of $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ did you get? You need to choose them so that the density integrates to 1 and $x f(x)$ integrates to 2.

Comment: I got 3 for both as i said in the post

Comment: And I verified by recalculating $E[X]$ and integrating $f(x)$ which got me the values 2 and 1

Comment: It's unclear why Tchebychev is needed here: you can easily find $a$ exactly from your solution to (1). Yes, the variance diverges: it is indeed confusing that you are asked to invoke an inequality that doesn't apply.

Comment: You are correct; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution for a comparison.  The variance is indeed infinite for $a \leq 3$ (in this parameterization; in the usual parameterization, $a \leq 2$.)   I wonder if the question really wanted Markov's inequality?  Or possibly it's a trick question?

Comment: I highly doubt they wanted Markov's inequality as we haven't treated it yet , it may be a trick question I guess.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality):

> The term Chebyshev's inequality may also refer to Markov's inequality, especially in the context of analysis.

By Markov's inequality with $|X-2|$,

$$P(|X-2|>a) \le \frac{E[|X-2|]}{a} = \frac1a$$

By choosing $a=100$, we have

$$P(|X-2|>100) \le 0.01$$

Note: There are other variations or collaries of Markov's inequality/Chebyshev's inequality. See: [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality#Other_corollaries), [Concentration inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality),

---

Alternatively, we can compute

$$P(|X-2|>a) = \int_{2-a}^{2+a} \frac{2}{x^3} dx > 0.99$$